# Convert an empty tag in XML to java attribute using jackson-dataformat-xml library

Tags: java, xml, spring-boot, jackson, xml-deserialization

I have below `XML` which need to be converted to `POJO` in `Spring Boot` app. I am using `jackson-dataformat-xml` module for this.

```
<Root>
    <Element1 ns="xxx">
        <Element2/>
    </Element1>
</Root>
```

**Root Pojo:**

```
@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "Root")
public class Root {
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "Element1")
    private Element1 element1;

    public String getElement1() {
        return element1;
    }

    public void setElement1(String element1) {
        this.element1 = element1;
    }
}
```

**Element1 Pojo:**

```
public class Element1 {
    @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true)
    private String ns;
    
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "Element2")
    private boolean element2;

    public boolean getElement2() {
        return element2;
    }

    public void setElement2(boolean element2) {
        this.element2 = element2;
    }
}
```

Property `element2` in `Element1` is always set to `false`. Is there any way to set it to `true` if **Element2** tag is present; otherwise `false`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default `Jackson` uses `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer` class do deserialise given `XML` element to `POJO`. This deserialiser invokes `setter` method only if corresponding node exists in `XML` payload. In case, node doesn't exist in payload - `setter` method is not invoked. We can utilize this behaviour.

Because we want to set always `true` we should create new private setter method and force `Jackson` to use it with `@JacksonXmlProperty` annotation. Below you can see example:

```
class Element1 {
    @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true)
    private String ns;

    private boolean element2;

    public boolean getElement2() {
        return element2;
    }

    public void setElement2(boolean element2) {
        this.element2 = element2;
    }

    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "Element2")
    private void setElement2ByJackson(boolean ignored) {
        this.element2 = true;
    }
}
```